# Twitching scrolling indicator of ListView with dynamic-height items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a ListView wrapped in Scrollbar. ListView has items with dynamic height.
The problem is the scrolling indicator twitching on scroll. Here is gif demonstrating the problem (pay attention to the scroll bar on the right):

[image]

I came to Flutter from iOS where I've been solving such problem by implementing `estimatedHeightForRow` method of UITableViewDelegate, which allows table (or ListView) to estimate entire height of its dynamic content and show scrolling indicator at the right position.

Does Flutter have similar solution?

Here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ListView.separated(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16, bottom: 16),
        separatorBuilder: (context, position) => Divider(),
        itemCount: listViewItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          final model = listViewItems[position];
          return OrderItemWidget(model: model);
        },
      ),
    );
```

Comment: @someuser Thanks, but this GitHub issue is about smooth scroll. I have no problems with smooth scroll, only with a scroll bar.

Comment: I don't think they are the same, probably there is misunderstanding

Comment: Obviously Flutter developer misunderstood the issue. Smooth scrolling issue is not the same as twitching scrollbar. I wrote a comment on GitHub.

Comment: This does look like an issue. Feel free to file a new issue for this :)

Comment: Have you found a fix for this issue? I'm facing the exact same issue, but for me the effect is even worse, the elements that I display are more uneven. I desperately need the virtual scroll feature to improve performance. But the scroll positioning is total garbage...